# putting elements between XML tags into parrallel lists/arrays

Tags: python, xml, string, list

I have a project where I am supposed to take name, price, description, and calories into separate arrays. We **CANNOT** use XML parsers, and the XML tags are giving me serious issues. This is the data format for the file we are creating arrays from:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <breakfast_menu>
      <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple 
         syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
      </food>
```

I can't seem to find resources on how to pull the data between XML tags to the array. Again, tags are giving me a serious headache. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: "We CANNOT use XML parsers" - Why? That requirement is quite strange.

Comment: start by uploading a **VALID** XML. Explain why you cant use a parser.

Comment: Sorry, first post ever here - should I repost it? Our class cannot use parsers because the answer is apparently available online somewhere. String methods only

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot use parser and you know your data will be formatted like this you can just read the xml as string and look for substrings with regex:

```
import re

xml_string = """
<breakfast_menu>
  <food>
    <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
    <price>$5.95</price>
    <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real 
 maple 
     syrup</description>
    <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
"""

regexs = {
     "name":"<name>([^<]*)</name>",
     "price":"<price>([^<]*)</price>",
     "description":"<description>([^<]*)</description>",
     "calories":"<calories>([^<]*)</calories>"
}

data = {title: [] for title in regexs.keys()}

for title, regex in regexs.items():
  for element in re.findall(regex, xml_string):
       data[title].append(element)
```

Output

```
data
{
 'calories': ['650'],
 'description': ['Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real \n  maple \n      syrup'],
 'name': ['Belgian Waffles'],
 'price': ['$5.95']
 }
```

Comment: "...into separate arrays"